# Small error with recycler view

Tags: android, loops, android-recyclerview, textview

Have this Recyclerview which is almost perfect. I say almost, because everything is working, images, plus and minus buttons, even got it to remember the values of the text fields when you scroll it out of the screen and back. Well most of them.

I am missing something here, and I cant find it, so I asking some help please. If I scroll the view out of the screen, whether top or bottom, it remembers the value of the text fields (which I want), but the moment I use the "cases minus button" (only that button), it changes the pallets value (pallets_text_view) to the cases value (cases_text_view) when I scroll it back on the screen.

Please note, only when I touch the "cases minus button". All the others works fine, the "cases plus button" and both pallet buttons, the text doesn't get changed when I scroll the row off the screen and back onto the screen, only after I taped the "pallets minus button".

[image: After I scrolled up and then back.]

See the image, this is after I scrolled out of the screen and back.  Top one (Black Label) I didn't touch, the Brutal Fruit I tapped the cases -1 button (went to 11 and the used it to get back to 10)

I know it must be some loop somewhere, but eish, I can't see it. Help would be thankful for.

Here is my CustomAdapter:

```
        public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context ctx;

public CustomAdapter(Context ctx) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
@Override
public CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvBrand.setText((CharSequence) modelArrayList.get(position).getBrand());
    holder.tvImage.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getImage())));
    holder.tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getNumberCases()));
    holder.tvPallet_size.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getPallet_size()));
    holder.tvPallets.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getNumber()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelArrayList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    protected Button btn_cases_plus, btn_cases_minus, btn_pallets_plus, btn_pallets_minus;
    protected ImageView tvImage;
    private TextView tvBrand, tvCases, tvPallets, tvPallet_size;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvBrand = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.brand_name);
        tvImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.beer_logo);
        tvCases = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
        tvPallet_size = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pallets_size);
        tvPallets = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pallets_text_view);
        btn_cases_plus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.casePlus1);
        btn_cases_minus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.caseMinus1);
        btn_pallets_plus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.palletsPlus1);
        btn_pallets_minus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.palletsMinus1);

        btn_cases_plus.setTag(R.integer.btn_cases_plus_view, itemView);
        btn_cases_minus.setTag(R.integer.btn_cases_minus_view, itemView);
        btn_cases_plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_cases_minus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pallets_plus.setTag(R.integer.btn_pallets_plus_view, itemView);
        btn_pallets_minus.setTag(R.integer.btn_pallets_minus_view, itemView);
        btn_pallets_plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pallets_minus.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    // onClick Listener for view
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == btn_pallets_plus.getId()) {
        View tempview = (View) btn_pallets_plus.getTag(R.integer.btn_pallets_plus_view);
        TextView tvPallets = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.pallets_text_view);
        TextView tvCases = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
        TextView tvPallet_size = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.pallets_size);
        int numberPallets = Integer.parseInt(tvPallets.getText().toString()) + 1;
        tvPallets.setText(String.valueOf(numberPallets));
        int numberCases = Integer.parseInt(tvPallets.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(tvPallet_size.getText().toString());
        tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(numberCases));
        modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumber(numberPallets);
        modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumberCases(numberCases);
    }
        else if (v.getId() == btn_pallets_minus.getId()) {
            View tempview = (View) btn_pallets_minus.getTag(R.integer.btn_pallets_minus_view);
            TextView tvPallets = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.pallets_text_view);
            TextView tvCases = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
            TextView tvPallet_size = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.pallets_size);
            int numberPallets = Integer.parseInt(tvPallets.getText().toString()) - 1;
            tvPallets.setText(String.valueOf(numberPallets));
            int numberCases = Integer.parseInt(tvPallets.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(tvPallet_size.getText().toString());
            tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(numberCases));
            if (numberPallets == 0 || numberPallets < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "You cannot order less than one pallet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                tvPallets.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            }
            modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumber(numberPallets);
            modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumberCases(numberCases);
        }

         else if (v.getId() == btn_cases_plus.getId()){
            View tempview = (View) btn_cases_plus.getTag(R.integer.btn_cases_plus_view);
            TextView tvPallets = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.pallets_text_view);
            TextView tvCases = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
            TextView tvPallet_size = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.pallets_size);
            int numberCases = Integer.parseInt(tvCases.getText().toString()) + 1;
            tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(numberCases));
            modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumberCases(numberCases);

        } else if (v.getId() == btn_cases_minus.getId()) {
            View tempview = (View) btn_cases_minus.getTag(R.integer.btn_cases_minus_view);
            TextView tvPallets = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.pallets_text_view);
            TextView tvCases = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
            TextView tvPallet_size = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.pallets_size);
            int numberCases = Integer.parseInt(tvCases.getText().toString()) - 1;
            tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(numberCases));
            if (numberCases == 0 || numberCases < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "You cannot order less than one case", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            }
            modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumber(numberCases);
        }
            }}
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you take a good look at some examples on how to use the `RecyclerView` in particular how to use `ViewHolder`!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are allocating the result to the wrong object:

In your `else if btn_case_plus.getId` condition you use this:

```
  modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumberCases(numberCases);
```

But in your  `else if (v.getId() == btn_cases_minus.getId()` condition you use:

```
  modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumber(numberCases);
```

I'm assuming this is your error. It should be `.setNumberCases(numberCases)`.

Comment: It is indeed. Thank you very much. As you can see from my code I'm quite new to Java. I'm currently in the retail sector. And in this trade we have a thing, we say you get "store blind", meaning you start to miss certain things, mainly because you're in the store the whole time, you start to get use to it being like that, not noticing its wrong. I think there must be a term like "code blind", which was what happened here. I spend the whole yesterday looking at my code, and I didn't see it, hence I posted it here hoping someone else might notice it (probably on fist glance). Tanks again.